# ASP.Net C# ResolveClientUrl inside Class

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, relative-path, resolveclienturl

I have the following code:

```
public class NavigationPath
{
    private string menuItems = "<li>" +
                                    "<a href=\"#\">home</a>" +
                               "</li>";
```

But I would like to have:

```
public class NavigationPath
{
    private string menuItems = "<li>" +
                                    "<a href=\"" + ResolveClientUrl("~/home.aspx") + "\">re</a>" +
                               "</li>";
```

However, I am not able to use ResolveClientUrl inside a Class. Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

ResolveClientUrl is a member of the System.Web.UI.Control class, hence it's accessible directly as:

```
var url = ResolveClientUrl("~/Some/Url/");
```

when called within the code of your asp.net page.

To use it inside a class you're going to have to pass the Page (or a control on the page) into the class in its constructor. Even then I'm not sure you'd be able to use it in the way you've indicated. You'd probably have to do something similar to:

```
public class NavigationPath
{
  private string menuItems = string.Empty;

  public NavigationPath(Page page)
  {
    menuItems = "<li>" + "<a href=\"" + page.ResolveClientUrl("~/Home.aspx") + "\">home</a>" + "</li>";
  }
}
```

And then inside your asp.net page do something like:

```
var navPath = new NavigationPage(this);
```

Answer (score 50):

Instead of calling `ResolveClientUrl` on the Page object (or any controls), you can also use `VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/home.aspx");` which will give you the same result as calling `ResolveUrl("~/home.aspx");`

Comment: This seems like the best solution if you ask me as you don't have to modify your code to get it to work!

Answer (score 1):

Bit old but might help someone.
Using :

```
using System.Web.UI;
```

And in code:

```
new Control().ResolveClientUrl("Path");
```

Worked for me, I use Web Application and not Web Site solution, though.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I found **VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute** to work very well for my purpose.

Worked perfectly:

```
protected void build_Menu() 
{

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    sb.Append("<li><a href='" + VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/Default.aspx'>Home</a></li>"));
    sb.Append("<li><a href='" + VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/CARS/Default.aspx'>Cars</a></li>"));
    sb.Append("<li><a href='" + VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/AIRPLANES/Default.aspx'>Airplanes</a></li>"));
    sb.Append("<li><a href='" + VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/MOTORCYCLES/Default.aspx'>Motorcycles</a></li>"));
    sb.Append("<li><a href='" + VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/REPORTS/Default.aspx'>Reports</a></li>"));
    sb.Append("<li><a href='" + VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/MANUALS/Default.aspx'>Manuals</a> </li>"));
    sb.Append("<li><a href='" + VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/ADMINISTRATION/Default.aspx'>Administration</a></li>"));


    MENUfromCodeBehind.Text = sb.ToString();

}
```