# Calling ResolveClientUrl within a static web method (ASPNet Web Forms)

Tags: asp.net, .net, webforms

I'm currently having trouble finding a way to call ResolveClientUrl within the context of a static web method inside of a ASP.Net Web Forms page.

I'm using jQuery Ajax calls to interact with WebForms as documented here: http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/ which is the reason why the WebMethod needs to be static. Problem is that within the WebMethod I need to generate an URL and append a query string to it, and I would like to play it safe and pass it through ResolveClientUrl before appending the query string.

Is there any way I can work around this, or does .Net provide an alternate static method that does more or less the same thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible if called from a web page using:

public static void DoThis()
{
     Page page = HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page;
}

However, if you are in a web method, it's not going to be the page as the handler; its a handler for the web request.  I used this approach from JavaScript, and it did work:

http://iridescence.no/post/Resolving-relative-URLe28099s-from-JavaScript.aspx

HTH.

Comment: It almost feels like a *hack*. However, it's dead simple and it gets the job done. Also, I feel like it's my only choice. Great job, thanks!

Answer (score 11):

from...
[ASP.Net C# ResolveClientUrl inside Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2238519/asp-net-c-sharp-resolveclienturl-inside-class)

Instead of calling `ResolveClientUrl` on the Page object (or any controls), you can also use `Web.VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/home.aspx");` which will give you the same result as calling `ResolveUrl("~/home.aspx");`